# Htaccess not working when hyphen (-) is used in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have the below code in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .?- [S=2]
RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1&bb=$2 [NE,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

and when I pass the below url

```
http://example.com/abc/some-example?id=123
```

As per me I am supposed to ge `$aa = some-example` and `$id = 123` in PHP

but I am getting the below error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /abc/[S=2] was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

and the above .htaccess file works fine when I pass the url as below

```
http://example.com/abc/someexample?id=123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a space before the dash on this line:

```
RewriteRule .?- [S=2]
```

Should be:

```
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
```

**EDIT**: Why do you even have this rule? Try removing it.

As far as I can tell, if the request doesn't match a specific file, you're telling apache to skip your next two rules, which results in a 404 instead of a rewrite.

You might also want to add a rule at the end for a friendly 404 page in case the url requested doesn't match your rewrite regexes.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the help. 
if i give space then every path I give is showing me the error below
`Not Found

The requested URL /a/someexample/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: after googling online I found that what you have suggested is right way of doing. But, I dont know why I am not getting the output I am looking for. :(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ryan,

Changing my

`RewriteRule .?- [s=2]`

to

```
RewriteRule ./ - [s=2]
```

helped me get what I was looking for

thanks to Ryan again.

Comment: Are you sure you even need the rule at all? What happens if you remove the line?

Comment: that was true. I didnot want the next line that I had.. :(.. `RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1 [NE,L,QSA]`..

Comment: Glad it worked. If my answer was the correct one, please mark it as the answer.